# RestSharp Log In Issues

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am attempting to pull an access token from a website with RestSharp. However after I have logged in and make the request, the response is just asking me to log in again. Every time I make a new request it acts like I have never logged in. Is there something extra that I need to have so that information is maintained throughout my requests?

Here is the code for the login and authorization-needed to retrieve the access token.

```
private RestClient client;
private RestRequest request;
private IRestResponse response;

public bool GetAuthenticityToken(string username, string password)
{
        client = new RestClient("https://www.website.com");
        client.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();

        authorize();
        signIn(username, password);

        return false;
}

public IRestResponse signIn(string username, string password)
{
        Debug.WriteLine("Begin Signin");

        client.Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("user[email]", username, "user[password]", password);
        request = new RestRequest("users/sign_in", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        request.AddParameter("commit", "Sign in");
        response = client.Execute(request);

        Debug.WriteLine("Done Signin");

        Debug.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri);
        Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);

        return response;
}

public IRestResponse authorize()
{
        request = new RestRequest("oauth/authorize", Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        request.AddParameter("response_type", "code");
        request.AddParameter("client_id", consumerID);
        request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", redirectURL);
        response = client.Execute(request);

        Debug.WriteLine(response.ResponseUri);
        Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);

        return response;
}
```